# C# Bug in Threading.Task.Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is this bug in Parallel.For?

```
   public class DataPoint
        {
            public int Game { get; set; }
            public byte Card { get; set; }
            public byte Location { get; set; }
            public DataPoint(int g,byte c,byte Loc)
            {
                Game = g;
                Card = c;
                Location = Loc;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",Game,Card,Location);
            }
        }
```

It must be a bug in Parallel.For

```
private static System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<DataPoint> FillData()
    {
        var points = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<DataPoint>();
        long c = 32768;
        long z = 0;
        Parallel.For(z, c, (i) =>
        {
            points.Add(new DataPoint( rand.Next(1, 100001),
                                      (byte)rand.Next(1, 144),
                                      (byte)rand.Next(1, 40)));
            });
        return points;
    }
```

works

```
private static System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<DataPoint> FillData()
    {
        var points = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<DataPoint>();
        long c = 32769;
        long z = 0;
        Parallel.For(z, c, (i) =>
        {
            points.Add(new DataPoint( rand.Next(1, 100001),
                                      (byte)rand.Next(1, 144),
                                      (byte)rand.Next(1, 40)));
            });
        return points;
    }
```

Doesn't Defaults each to {1,1,1}

Comment: But there is a number where is returns, {1,1,1} for all entries. 125000

Comment: It is a problem if the each of entry should be highly randomised.

Comment: Your problem is well-known; it is called the **select isn't broken** problem. (http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) That is, the incorrect belief that when **you** cause a bug in **your own program**, that the "real" bug must actually be an obvious bug that somehow managed to be released in a well-tested and heavily-debugged library. Sure, sometimes there are bugs in libraries and compilers. I've caused plenty of those. But most of the time, the right starting assumption is that *your* code is the thing that is wrong.

Comment: But it still begs the question of what are the mechanic which causes the items in already the ConcurrentBag suddenly be changed to the same value, it makes no sense to me, some partial quantity of the list yeah.

Comment: @Adam: They're not changed _after_ they are Added.

Comment: [image of effect](http://img703.imageshack.us/i/concurrentbag.jpg).  4000000 Items, first 637477 are [1, 1, 1]. Why? (You told me about it not being threadsafe.) But I want to know what are the mechanics which result in this.

Comment: If you really want thread-safe randomness, Jon Skeet has already done the work for you in his [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx) class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Random class is explicitly documented as *not* Thread-safe.

You are using the wrong class at the wrong place+time in the wrong way.

There is  no bug in the library.

### Edit

The short solution here is that `Random()` and `Parallel.For()` don't go together well. Just replace the Parallel.For with a normal `for(;;)` loop.  For 32k elements, you won't notice the difference.

If you still want it in parallel, you'll have to split the range, run a couple of Tasks and give each Task it's own Random instance.

Comment: I assure you that there *is* a bug in the library. It's just that this isn't it.

Comment: @Eric: As long as it's just the one, I think we can live with that.

Answer (score 6):

Randoms are never good in multithreaded situations.

Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: Daniel A. White: If that is so, how do I make it good, show constructive advice, not just a commentary. (How else am I'm going to improve?)

Comment: The documentation says it is if is shared, which it is.

Comment: @Adam: You asked if there was a bug int the TPL. The answer is: No. If you want more constructive answers, ask a better question. Sorry to be picking on you, but do think about how Q+A works.

Comment: Why? What constitute a better question?.  At some value (the code would result a collection containing for each entry {1,1,1}, but a smaller value it wouldn't. Can you see how this could be interpreted as an error in the Parallel.For method?

Comment: @Adam: you've been given more than enough hints how to fix the issue. You did not discover a bug in the library, but one in your code: use of non thread-safe code in concurrent mode. The fix is trivial, simply declare and initialize a new local `rand` inside your Task delegate.

Comment: @Remus: That would land us in 1 of the most asked questions here, use of many auto-seeded Random's in sequence. Bad suggestion.

Comment: @Henk: right. Use InterlockedIncrement to generate seed on each task and construct the Random() with the II result. Seed initial value of the incremented value with random from outside the delegate. I guess when start using Parallel.Whatever, one is expected to know how to resolve such issues, or perhaps I expect too much...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awesome blog post by a MSFT employee on different methods to handle generating random numbers within Parallel loops and their performance implications:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx